# SQLite удаление данных таблицы

Tags: android, sqlite

Удаляю данные с таблицы. После чего заново начинаю её заполнять . Но ключ (_id) не записывает как первое значение. А продолжает дальше счет. Как его сбросить?

```
//Добавление данных
    public long setInsert(String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values)
    {
        return myDataBase.insert("NicknamePersony", nullColumnHack, values);
    }


//Удаление данных
public  void delete(String table)
{
    myDataBase.delete("NicknamePersony", null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы сбросить **AUTOINCREMENT** нужно после удаления всех записей таблицы выполнить следующий запрос: `db.execSQL("DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE NAME = '" + TABLE_NAME + "'");`, где `TABLE_NAME` - имя вашей таблицы.

**Источник:** https://stackoverflow.com/q/9759502/2506123

**Update:** Но, а если вы не хотите удалять все записи, то читайте, что написано в ответе @pavlofff.

Comment: Спасибо, работает))

Answer (score 2):

Никак, это не требуется. ID это не счетчик позиции, а **уникальный** идентификатор. В одной таблице не может быть двух одинаковых ID, не важно были удалены записи или нет иначе будет нарушена одна из основновных концепций реляционной базы данных.

Comment: Спасибо)) разобрался